# Salesforce Emails Limits

Tags: limits, email2case, singleemailmessage

I am using both Apex and Flow( each for different scenario) to send acknowledgement emails to customers on case creation. From Apex I am using ***Messaging.SingleEmailMessage*** to send emails. From flow I am invoking email Action.

As per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381534&type=1) General Email limit is 5000 . I want to understand if email send through both Apex and Flow or any other automation will be counted against this 5000 limit. As from other [Doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384947&type=1) SingleEmailMessage itself has 5000 limit

Note:- I am not using Auto Acknowledgement as I have to include multiple recipients based on business criteria.

Comment: For orgs created before Spring '19, this daily limit applies only to emails sent via Apex and Salesforce APIs (excluding REST APIs). In orgs created after Spring '19, this daily limit also applies to email alerts, simple email actions, Send Email actions in flows, and REST APIs.   Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks @Sai . Do you have any supporting document for this?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.allocations_email_general.htm&type=5) it is mentioned  as below.

> Each licensed organization can send a single email to up to 5,000 external email addresses per day. For orgs created before Spring '19, this daily limit applies only to emails sent via Apex and Salesforce APIs (excluding REST APIs). In orgs created after Spring '19, this daily limit also applies to email alerts, simple email actions, Send Email actions in flows, and REST APIs.

This [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.limitations_email_mass.htm&type=5) also specifies more details about it

Comment: As per this https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386230&type=1 I can check  SingleEmailMessage  limit form workbench. Could you please suggest how can we check general Limit(i.e email sent through both Apex and flow or any other automation)

Comment: @AbhinavThakur, I guess that should give you all the limit. Is it not showing it ?

Comment: Not actually Sai, Initially I was also under same impression .However when I checked  count only decrease if I triggered email from Apex using Messaging.SingleEmailMessage not when it triggered from Flow. that where all confusion arises around limits where flow email is getting counted or not. If possible for you please help me on this. :)

Comment: Can you confirm to whom you are triggering the email is it for external email id?

Comment: Yes , I am dropping email from my personalId to Email2Case routing addresss of my organisation

Comment: @AbhinavThakur, Can you log a Case to salesforce support and share the Case Number here so I can ask the team to look into the limits and confirm you.

Comment: Thanks! Sai for all your help. If at all we need to raise case for this I will share the case no here.